# Bootstrap for a model with crossed random factors in R (bootMer)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I want to bootstrap my model with two random factors, subject and item, which are crossed. I have specified my model as follows:

```
lmer(outcome ~ predictor_level1 + predictor_level2 + (1 | subject) + (1 | item), data = df)
```

I know that `bootMer` or `lmeresampler` are two *R* packages that can be used to do bootstrapping easily, but it seems that `lmeresampler` only supports the parametric bootstrap for crossed random factors. I could not find more information about bootMer's support for semi-parametric (or residual bootstrapping) with crossed random factors. Since residual bootstrapping seems to be more robust, I would like to use this method. So here are my questions:

1. Does anyone have some information, if `bootMer` supports residual bootstrap for crossed random factors? If not, can anyone recommend an other R package that supports this option for crossed random factors?
2. Does anyone know which semi-parametric bootstrap method is implemented in bootMet? Is it the one of [Carpenter, Goldstein and Rasbash (2003)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1467-9876.00415)?
3. Has anyone some literature tips on bootstrapping for crossed random factors? This would be highly appreciated, since I'm not sure how bootstrapping for crossed factors differs from normal level 2 nested models.